# CSS huge one-line file indentation doesn't work

Tags: css, vim, indentation

I am trying to indent in a sensible way [this CSS file](https://raw.github.com/macjasp/cleanpress/master/source/stylesheets/screen.css). My default editor is VIM. I tried multiple times using `visual-select-all + =`, didn't work `gg=G` didn't work either.

I have tried to use `css.vim` but still nothing. Is there automated way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use an external utility.

```
$ npm install cssbeautify
$ vim screen.css

:%!cssbeautify %
```

## Presto!

---

*before*

[image: pre]

*after*

[image: post]

Comment: That's the best solution I've seen so far. I ended up using [vim-jsbeautify](https://github.com/maksimr/vim-jsbeautify). Same approach works for HTML/CSS/JS :-) thanks!

Comment: personally, I had to install cssbeautify globally in order to be able to use it as above (use -g switch with npm install)

Answer (score 4):

Vim's indenting will not break nor join lines; it only adjusts the leading indent of each line.  If you want to use vim's built-in indenting, then you first have to break the one-line CSS file into separate lines.  A good start is to add a newline after each (opening or closing) brace and each semicolon:

```
:%s/[{;}]/&\r/g
```

If you install an external program, as @Ярослав Рахматуллин suggests, then you might decide to use that with the `=` commands:

```
:help 'equalprg'
```

Comment: Is \r equivalent to verbatim-insert [return] ?

Comment: Yes:  see `:help sub-replace-special`.

Answer (score 0):

Without any external software, only with Vim:

1. Split the big line in one rule per line:

```
%s/\(.\{-}{.\{-}}\)/\r\1/gc
```

2. Reformat: first step. For each rule put all properties in one line:

```
%s/\(.\{-}{\)\(.\{-}\)\(}\)/\1\r\t\2\r\3\r/gc
```

3. Reformat: second step. Split properties one per line:

```
%s/;/;\r\t/gc
```

Maybe you can do it easier, but this works.

For the explanation of the regex see https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html and https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#sub-replace-special

Answer (score -1):

you can always try "online [whateveryouneed]" on google

http://www.lonniebest.com/FormatCSS/

hope it works

Comment: This isn't what OP is asking about.