# Vim: reformat CSS from one-line to multi-line

Tags: css, vim

I have some css code in this format:

```
a { color: #333; background-color: #fff; } 
a:visited { color: #aaa; background-color: #555; }
```

I want to get it in this format:

```
a { 
    color: #333; 
    background-color: #fff; 
} 
a:visited {
    color: #aaa; 
    background-color: #555; 
}
```

Is there an easy way to do that? I know I can write a macro to do that, but I was hoping there was a better/easier solution. Ideally, I'd like to be able to select the lines and do something like `gq`.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22212446/css-huge-one-line-file-indentation-doesnt-work.  In fact, @Kent's answer here is very similar to my answer there.

Comment: May also want to look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422866/using-vi-how-can-i-make-css-rules-into-one-liners Which is the inverse, but has useful solutions. I even made a small folding script from it: https://gist.github.com/PeterRincker/9977119

Answer (score 23, accepted):

if the filetype has already been set as `CSS`, you can try:

```
:%s/[{;}]/&\r/g|norm! =gg
```

at least it works for your example:

[image]

Comment: I like this!! (probably more than my answer) - Although, with my vi I only got the last property of each block tabbed in :-(

Comment: Regex *all* the things.

Comment: I would do it the same way, except I would use two separate lines.  Vim's internal reformatting only changes indentation.  It does not add or remove line breaks.  So first use `:s` to break the lines, then `gg=G` or equivalent.  If you want something more reliable than regular expressions, use an external program as in Ingo Karkat's answer.

Comment: Awesome. Could you tell me what `s/[{;}]/&\r/g` does? I know it's some kind of regex substitution, but I'm mystified about the `[{;}]`.

Comment: it adds a new line after each `{ or ; or }`. @Jono

Comment: Worked great for me - I hate plugins if there is a clean solution and this is pretty nice!

Comment: For minified files, it may require you to additionally run `%s/\v([^};])\}/\1\;\r}\r/g|norm! =gg` in order to fix properties that don't have semicolons if they're the last property.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [cssbeautify](https://www.npmjs.org/package/cssbeautify):

```
:%! css-beautify --file -
```

Comment: If you like the results of css-beautify, then you can use it instead of vim's internal reformatting.  Something like `:set equalprg=css-beautify` (untested).  See `:help 'equalprg'`.

Answer (score 0):

Not the definitive answer but something that might help get you in the right direction. I use a lot of vim files to sense check my code (different languages) and I have found with plugins I can copy my code in and have it nicely formatted on the fly (e.g. PEP-8 when doing python etc).
Hopefully this will be of some use to you: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2981

***TotalOpinion*** - (Sorry!) -
Congratulations on choosing the king of all editors!

Comment: King needs a queen... :)

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on this problem for a while. But in my case, I want to reformat the one-lined css file line by line, inspired by Kent's answer, I finally got this:

1. use visual mode to select a line or a few lines that you'd like to reformat
2. type `'<,'>s/[{;}]/&\r/g|norm! v'<=`

after you've done with the reformated css block, select only one css block in visual mode and press J (a capital j), then it'll become a nice one-line.

PS. Sorry about my poor English

Answer (score 0):

The Kent's reply dopn't work well with file more complex like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_downloads.asp) : (W3C reference CSS)

I do it in a different way:

1. Split the big line in one rule per line:

```
%s/\(.\{-}{.\{-}}\)/\r\1/gc
```

2. Reformat: first step. For each rule put all properties in one line:

```
%s/\(.\{-}{\)\(.\{-}\)\(}\)/\1\r\t\2\r\3\r/gc
```

3. reformat: second step. Split properties one per line:

```
%s/;/;\r\t/gc
```

Maybe you can do it in less step, but this works fine.